# How do i create a List of all colors there are from Color?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tried this now:

```
KnownColor[] colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
            foreach (KnownColor knowColor in colors)
            {
                Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);
            }
```

But im getting error on Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));

Error   14  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'System.Drawing.KnownColor[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In the end i want to have a List with all colors inside so i can use the List later with the colors. today i can make Color.Red or Color.Green... I want that i will have a List of all the colors on the Form1 and i will be able to select each time another color and it will change to the selected color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p.s.w.g has explained what's wrong with the existing code, but I'd probably just use LINQ to do it all in one go:

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
                 .Cast<KnownColor>() // Or cast the array
                 .Select(Color.FromKnownColor)
                 .ToList();
```

That will give you a `List<Color>` - it's not really clear what you mean by being able to select colours...

Comment: Jon Skeet i mean that for example in my code i have this line: brush.CenterColor = Color.PaleVioletRed; i dont want to change each time the Color and then run the program to see how the color looks like then stop the program change the color again...I want to have all the colors when im running the program and when i select a color it will change it on this line so i can see and change the colors in real time when the program is running.

Comment: @user3200169 If you're just trying to pick each different color in code, what's wrong with simply typing `PaleVioletRed`? I don't see how this `for`-loop helps.

Comment: @user3200169: What do you mean by "when I select a color"? In the debugger? As part of your UI? Anyway, if you wanted a `List<Color>`, this will get you one...

Comment: What i mean is in the code i type Color.Red then i run my program i see something in Red. Now i want to see how it looks like in Green so i need to stop the program and change the line to Color.Green now i needd to un the program again to see how it looks in green. Instead i want to run the program once and while the program is running to change the colors .

Comment: @user3200169: That *still* doesn't tell us how you're going to change the colours. Just having a list doesn't magically give you the ability to change the colour of elements. However, my code does what you wanted - it creates a `List<Color>` from all the known colours.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the array:

```
KnownColor[] colors = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
```

Alternatively, you can leave `colors` as an `Array` (either explicitly typed or implicitly typed) since your `foreach` iterator is typed as a `KnownColor`. This would work too:

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
foreach (KnownColor knowColor in colors)
{
    Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);
}
```